# Project module, how to choose default "relatedto" field value

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

Good morning everyone, I would like a tip on a small detail of the Projects module that makes my work difficult.

When a new project is created there is the possibility to relate it to either an organization or a contact,but in the field where it is chosen the default value is organization, so every time I create a new project I have to click on organization, select contact, and then choose the contact i want.

How can i get the default value on Contacts? Or at least break the relationship between Projects and Organizations (i don't need it)?

I tried to modify the table vtiger_field from the database, the fieldname is linktoaccountscontacts, and to modify the defaultvalue, but it does not work.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't need the relationship between Projects and Organizations you can delete it in the vtiger_fieldmodulerel table:

```
DELETE FROM vtiger_fieldmodulerel WHERE fieldid IN (SELECT fieldid FROM `vtiger_field` WHERE `fieldname`='linktoaccountscontacts') AND relmodule ='Accounts'
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
You solved a big problem for me and answered a question I had for a long time!

If it's not too much to ask, could you please explain to me how I can create relationships between two modules instead? Or change the type of relationship? I can't find up-to-date and clear documentation about this anywhere...